# Constantly getting html after sending Ajax post request to custom plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

It's my first plugin but I've tested everything I could find online and have been looking for a fix for days, but couldn't fix it. After the request is submitted, I get the whole page's html. There's nothing in the debug log and the echo from the ajax callback doesn't seem to work.

```
//PHP code
    public function __construct() {
        // Register and enqueue JavaScript file
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_isq_scripts' ), 999 );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_isq_ajax', array( $this, 'isq_ajax' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_isq_ajax', array( $this, 'isq_ajax' ) );    
        add_shortcode( 'isq_form', array( $this, 'isq_form_shortcode' ) );
    }
    public function register_isq_scripts() {
        wp_register_script( 'isq-js', ISQUESTION_PLUGIN_URL. 'core/includes/assets/js/isq.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
        wp_register_style( 'isq-css', ISQUESTION_PLUGIN_URL. 'core/includes/assets/css/isqstyles.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
        if ( is_page() && has_shortcode( get_post()->post_content, 'isq_form' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'isq-js' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'isq-css' );
            $rest_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'isq_nonce' );
            wp_localize_script( 'isq-js', 'isqData', array(
                'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'nonce' => $rest_nonce,
            ));
        }
    }
    public function isq_ajax() {
        
        if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'isq_nonce')) {
            $data = $_POST['data'];
            // $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
            global $wpdb;
            $name = sanitize_text_field( $data['name'] );
                        // ... rest of the code
            wp_send_json_success( array(
                'message' => 'Data saved successfully.'
            ) );
        } 
        wp_die();
    }
```

And Here's the ajax request from JavaScript. data is a JS object like this `data={'name': 'David'}`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: isqData.ajax_url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        'action': "isq_ajax",
        'nonce': isqData.nonce,
        'data': data,
    },
    success: function(d) {
        console.log(d)
    },
    error: function(d) {
        console.log(d)
    },
});
```

I tried using contentType: 'json', but it triggers ajax function's error.
I tried my ajax callback function in php without nonce but it seems it is not being triggered at all because echo and return_json functions are not working

Comment: _"I tried using contentType: 'json', but it triggers ajax function's error."_ - of course it will, if the response is not valid JSON. And even if your page did not return HTML, your response certainly would not be valid JSON, since you are making arbitrary output before it: `echo $_POST;` - which in itself already makes little sense, because you can not output an array with echo, that will only ever result in the _text_ `Array` (plus a notice/warning about array to string conversion.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. echo is there for debugging. removing it doesn't change the response I'm getting.What I don't understand is why the ajax success function of js is being triggered but nothing happens at the backend and its response is that page's html.

Comment: The success function triggers merely based on the status code of the response, not what the response body actually contains. You say you are getting "the" page's HTML, but _what_ page, exactly? The current page? Or a page containing some sort of error message perhaps?

Comment: The page's html that the request is being sent from. I tried rendering it to see if it contains any errors or messages, but it doesn't, it sends the same page as response, not the wp_send_json_success() message. I thought this was related to my ajax callback function from the plugin but none of the echo and wp_send_json_success itself and wp_send_json_error I once had are executed, so I'm wondering maybe this is related to something else, not the ajax callback...

Comment: Sounds like it did not enter your AJAX action to begin with then. If you tried to make an AJAX request with an `action` value that it does not find a registered callback for, you should get an error message saying so, IIRC. Rather suspecting that your request might not be going to the AJAX endpoint to begin with here? Please verify what URL it actually gets send to, via your browser dev tools (network panel.)

Comment: You're right, the problem might be related to the ajax function itself. The request is being sent like this domain/isq/?i=2&fullbody=please and fullbody=please is why I'm getting the page's html. I thought the issue might be related to action and nonce not being enclosed with quotation BUT the issue persists.

Comment: `'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),`, `url: isqData.ajax_url` - using the same name for the property in both places might help :-) This needs to be `isqData.ajaxurl` in the JS code.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the issue. I can't believe I spent this much time and also wasted your time for this stupid mistake. Much appreciated my friend.